# Saving Skype voicemail messages on a Mac

Tags: macos, audio, skype, file-format

I would like to save two voicemail messages that I received today through Skype.

[image]

I would like to do this quickly and get the source file if possible, or at least get the source file to open in an audio editor to save or convert it from source, rather than have to record the audio from my computer as I play the messages.
[This thread](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Video-Messages-Stored-Location-in-Mac/td-p/2318505) on the Skype forums suggests using an SQLite database browser but this is what happens what I open Main.db with SQL Lite and paste one of the links in my browser:

[image]

(I didn't get a code, since I exported this HTTPS address from a SQL database).

You would think that in this day and age there is a way to do it right from the app, but you'd be wrong (thank god for the feature "Edit Mood Message", though, right?).

After googling around, I read [this post](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac-archive/How-to-save-video-messages-to-a-file-on-Mac/td-p/3788573) and tried the *Video Message Exporter* app. Of course, as the name implies, it seems to have been designed to help download only *video* messages, and nothing appeared in the window of the app even as I played the messages.

One good thing about this link is that I found out about the folder `~Library/Application Support/Skype`, which probably contains the files I'm looking for.

Indeed, it seems that two files in the Username/voicemail folder correspond to the date and hour I played the messages for the first time. They are also in a file size range that corresponds to the length of the messages (one is 10 minutes, the other one is 4 minutes, one file is 1Mb, the other is 435Kb, it's almost proportional).

[image]

The problem is the file format for these files: I've never heard of ".dat" as an audio file format, and neither has Quicktime/VLC/MPEG Streamclip/Audacity... Or even Google.

Are these .DAT files the audio files I am looking for?

Can they be understood by a computer and converted to raw audio, .aiff or anything that would make sense as an audio format?

If not, can I make use of the HTTP addresses in the SQL Database and will they link to voice messages or only to videos?

If this fails, can I get other HTTP URLs directing me to the files I am looking for, from skype? (since Skype seems to know how these URLs were produced and even has a code system associated with them).

(This is all the same question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Save as" option on Skype 7.59 for Mac. The little dropdown arrow, where that normally would show, gives no options when clicked next to a voice message.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it on PC, but it'll most likely be the same for both, because the feature is included in Skype itself. The solution is so simple, you'll wonder why you didn't figure it out earlier (took me a while to notice it too :) ). Right-click on the blue voice message box. Several options will appear. One of them will be "Save as...". Click on that and voilà!

Comment: Doesn't seem to have that option [on OSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6E0e.png).